# Show whether the scalar projection is idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection, idempotents

A while ago I asked [*Show whether the vector projection is idempotent*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033533/show-whether-the-vector-projection-is-idempotent), which made it clear to me that the idempotency of the vector projection could be checked with a simple substitution.

Now I am thinking about the [scalar projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_projection), which takes vectors as input and returns a scalar. This contrasts to the vector projection that took in vectors and returned a scalar. How can the scalar projection really be an idempotent map if the image is a different space than the domain?

Comment: The scalar projection is not idempotent for the reason you provided.

Comment: @angryavian Okay, good to know that it isn't an [abstract projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics)). The terminology was confusing me.